# Is there some rational reason to free allocated resources in short living programs?

Tags: memory-management, language-agnostic, resources

There is a class of short living programs that are working this way:

```
1. Allocate some resources - memory, open files, etc.
2. Make some computations
3. Free allocated resources
4. Terminate
```

The same question is valid for the termination stages of long lived programs of the type:

```
1. Do some job
2. If not the end - goto 1
3. Free the resources still allocated
4. Terminate
```

Now, we know that the OS itself always cleans after the program termination. Is it really necessary to clean the allocated memory by our code, if it will be, with the same success, freed by the OS, one step further?

Can we safely omit the point 3 in the above examples? It is time and code after all.

**Clarification 1**: I am not talking about libraries where the code can be reused by someone in different context. I am asking about the finished programs, where the above structure is clean enough.

**Clarification 2**: The "good practices" are called so, because they are intended to prevent "bad effects". But if the bad effect is impossible to happen, are these practices still "good"? Or it is simply "tradition"?

Comment: As a child I do not have to clean up my room, the garbage collector does all the work. Now I am grown up, use C++ and clean up my room by myself. And yes, sometimes the OS supports me, but sometimes I have no OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's really a meaningful language-agnostic answer to this.

In languages that use a garbage collector, it's unlikely that the GC would run automatically before exit, and it would generally be quite pointless to manually force it to run (even if we assume you're using a language/library that allows you to do so).

In C++, resource acquisition should almost always happen in a constructor, and freeing that resource should normally happen in the matching destructor. In this case, writing the code without the proper destructor is almost certainly a bug -- you're simply writing a class that's incomplete and hoping that it'll only ever be used in a way that keeps that bug from manifesting itself.

In C, or anything else similar where you have to do the cleanup manually, I prefer to write the code to do that final cleanup, but *normally* comment it out. This can improve both speed and code size, as well as ensuring against any bugs in the code for freeing the data (pretty hard for code that isn't compiled to cause a problem).

Comment: +1 for the commented out cleaning code! Initially, the question was tagged as [assembly][c][c++]. But some (bad word here) removed [assembly] with the argument that the question has nothing to do with assembly language. As long as I am writing in assembly and don't want to mess with C/C++ (it is because of the religion) I removed C/C++ tags as well (in defiance) and tagged it as [language-agnostic]. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This depends very much on the OS. Most modern OS's will automatically free all resources when a program terminates, which maans that there is no actual requirement to free things before exiting the program.

But this is not *always* the case, in particular certain types of embedded OS's will have a simpler approach.

Of course, it also doesn't work very well when you (or more importantly, someone else) decide to take your code and turn it from a short running process to a long lived program...

Comment: This is most balanced answer nor now. But can you give some example for OS that will not clean after the program termination?

Comment: I have worked with "home-brew" OS's that wouldn't clean up properly. It's of course a nightmare, because if the program for some reason crashes/exits without cleaning up, you get problems. Not even old "DOS" or "CP/M" had this problem. But it's not unheard of. However, it's still good practice because it helps when you take your code that used to process 1 file and make a loop around it that processes ALL the files that you passed on the command-line... [I recently wrote some code that produced 115000 (give or take) files, and it wouldn't be very fun to delete if `rm *` said "out of memory"]

Comment: Well, in the example you gave (about file procesing) the loop through the command line arguments is points 1 and 2 in the my pseudocode, so we are not talking about it. On the other hand if you make a program that to process only one file and then start this program from the shell script for 100000 files, there will not be any memory leaks, because the OS will clean after every termination.

Comment: My point is that if you have some code that you have written, which doesn't clean up after itself, e.g. a function that gets the size of the file, allocate memory to store the content of the file, and then read in the content of the file to that memory, then process the content, and returns without freeing memory, relying on the termination to clear its memory. Now, imagine that you then change the code from `processFile(argv[1])` to `for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) processFile(argv[i]);`. It will work just fine for 5-10 files, but when you give it a HUGE number of files, it will fall over.

Comment: I am fully agree about this code, but your example simply is not what I am asking for. In this example, if **after** the for cycle, there is some memory allocation, the corresponding deallocation would fit in my question.

Comment: I fail to see the point of your last comment. My point is that in the case where the code handles only one file, you have one allocation that is cleared up as the code terminates. By adding a simple for-loop and altering the constant `1` to a variable `i`, we have now converted a working program with one single leak that gets cleared up, to one with potentially many thousands of leaks that may fail because it runs out of memory - and you have to fully understand `processFile` to understand that it's going to leak - which is why it's a bad idea to "let it leak".

Comment: Yes, but in order to convert it you have to add some code - for loop, a variable. So, how the memory free call is different? Only one more modification of the code in order to properly reuse if for another task.

Comment: Imagine that `processFile` is actually quite complex, and not just a five-ten line function... It may not be one single allocation either, it may be half a dozen different allocations in different places, for example. My point is still that "not freeing your allocatations" can lead to bugs when the code is modified/reused.

Answer (score 0):

You should ALWAYS clean up after yourself.  You can never tell when someone will take your code and use it in a different situation.

Coding up a complete solution is the correct thing to do in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked myself that question at some point too and after a small debate I came to the conclusion:

It is good practice to free resources in case you do decide to reuse that code in a larger project later. There is nothing worse then debugging old code. Do it right straight away and stick to good programming practices.